# Picking an OpenCL Library for C#/Silveright

Tags: c#, opencl, opentk, cloo

I'm interested in trying out OpenCL in a test project. But which library should I use?

I'm not even sure what my choices are. I'm looking for:

- Something that works at a high-level of abstraction (OpenCL is very low-level).
- Something that works with Silverlight/XNA and C#.

It seems like the following libraries exist:

- [Cloo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloo/)
- [OpenTk](http://www.opentk.com/)

Comment: What are your criteria / what are you looking for?  Just general recommendations?  What's your budget?

Comment: @Kieren I'm not sure; the higher-level the better; my budget is (sadly) $0.

Comment: Actually OpenTK uses Cloo for OpenCL bindings http://www.opentk.com/doc/compute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worth candidate might be [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com). I am not a specialist in C#, but it looks promising. To find something on a higher level of abstraction will be very difficult due to the nature of OpenCL. You need to write the OpenCL kernel in OpenCL C. The only abstraction change might be the handling of your OpenCL devices.